How to read CSV file with all variables in character using `vroom`?
How to read 'myfile.csv' with all variables in character using vroom ?
library(vroom)
'Below code can't work
input_file_2<- vroom('myfile.csv',colClasses = 'character')


You can use:
library(vroom)
vroom('myfile.csv', col_types = cols(.default = col_character()))

